# SEO switch from http to https

Tags: google-analytics, seo, google-search-console

2 months ago we moved our complete website from http:// to https://. At this moment google did still not process all of our 1500 pages which results in our google analytics->aquisition->search terms to tell us (not set) for 43% of our traffic.

How can we speed up te process at google for this? Keep in mind that: everything is 301 redirected, our sitemap is on https, we made a new webmaster tools entity.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: No, this was first i think, too. The problem is how to implement cross Domain tracking in Analytics. See below. The question is not so good.

Answer (score -1):

It needs Time.
The best way way to increase your crawl budget is to speed up your site. Crawl Budget is a time resource.
You can Check the crawl budget in the Google Search Console under how many site are crawled / day. Site means in the Diagramm request's. You can see if the download time goes down the crawls per day goes up. Same if you reduce request like cobinine CSS, reduce JS, use CDN etc.

Comment: Our download time in the console is 332ms. Average pages per day is 755 so everything could be crawled in 2-3 days. Anything that could be wrong?

Comment: Download time is the Time to First Byte (TTFB) not realy the download himself. My site has 35-100ms. And Pages crawled per day are crawler request (css,js,image,xml,...) and not a complete crawled website. Keep this in mind. My value ist 20K/day. This crawl budget depend on many factor's and is not a quality sign. And usually after a relaunch it takes up to 3 month everything keeps back. Check your logfile for failures like 403 or something like this (it is a request, too).

Comment: And 43% search terms (not set) ist great. The most website today becomes ~80-90% (not set) traffic from Google.
Sorry you talk about (not set) above or traffic lost?

Comment: We do not lose the traffic. But in google our pages are listed with http:// in stead of https://. This results in a 301 redirect, losing the referral data so the keywords are lost. Or is the data lost somewhere else?

Comment: Ahh.. now I understand. Sorry. Look for cross domain tracking in analytics.